# How to calculate KE using only mass and height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, mass, potential

For our physics (high school level) group project, we were asked to modify a selected toy so that it produces an energy output of at least or roughly 110% (10% more) compared to the original toy.

Our toy is a pull-back toy (you can find it by searching "McDonald's Happy Meal Snoopy Toy" and it's the one with the girl on the sledge). Its mass is **234g** and we will be modifying the toy by removing the female character on it. This will reduce the mass to **213g** and this should theoretically increase the speed and in turn the energy output.

We tested the toy by placing it on a table with a height of 2m. We marked a starting line, and pulled the toy back 30cm to another marked line, repeating thrice (3 times) and then releasing. We repeated the whole process 3 times and the average distance travelled was 2.23m. The average time travelled (braking naturally) was 5.1s. Therefore:

$$V = \frac{distance}{time}$$
$$V = \frac{2.23}{5.1}$$
$$V \approx 0.437m/s$$

As part of the task, we were required to **calculate the gravitational potential energy (GPE) and kinetic energy (KE) of both toys** (control/original and modified), all calculations in Joules (not Newtons) to justify our modification. Here are our calculations:

*GPE of control toy:*

$$GPE = mgh$$
$$GPE = 0.234 \times{9.8} \times{2}$$
$$GPE = 4.5864J$$

*KE of control toy:*

$$KE = \frac{mv^{2}}{2}$$
$$KE = \frac{0.234 \times{0.437^{2}}}{2}$$
$$KE = 0.022343373J$$

*GPE of modified toy:*

$$GPE = mgh$$
$$GPE = 0.213 \times{9.8} \times{2}$$
$$GPE = 4.1748J$$

The question I have is: **how do I calculate the KE this toy would have?** We are required to calculate this without actually conducting tests to find the real result. I can already complete the following:

*KE of modified toy:*

$$KE = \frac{mv^{2}}{2}$$
$$KE = \frac{0.213 \times{?^{2}}}{2}$$

The issue is the velocity. I only have the values for mass and height, and *the result I get using the derived formula from the law of conservation of energy is the same as the GPE value.* **Is this what is to be expected or not? And if it isn't, what formula do I use?**

Given that formula ($V = \sqrt{2gh}$), I can calculate the following:

$$V = \sqrt{2gh}$$
$$V = \sqrt{2 \times{9.8} \times{2}}$$
$$V = \sqrt{39.2}$$
$$V \approx 6.261m/s$$

So subsituting this into the kinetic energy formula, this is what I get:

$$KE = \frac{mv^{2}}{2}$$
$$KE = \frac{0.213 \times{6.261^{2}}}{2}$$
$$KE = \frac{0.213 \times{39.2}}{2}$$
$$KE = 4.1748J = GPE$$

---

**Solution (solved by @Steeven on 6 September 2016 at 8:05:19am GMT+0):**

Using the formula for conservation of momentum, we can calculate the following:

$$\sum{p_{before}} = \sum{p_{after}}$$
$$p_{before} = p_{after}$$

And therefore $p_{before} = p_{after} ⇔ m_{1} v_{1}=m_{2} v_{2}$ so we can solve for $V_{2}$ as below:

$$V_{2} = \frac{m_{1}v_{1}}{m_{2}}$$
$$V_{2} = \frac{0.234 \times{0.437}}{0.213}$$
$$V_{2} \approx 0.48m/s$$

And the next step is to input this value into the kinetic energy formula as follows:

$$KE = \frac{mv^{2}}{2}$$
$$KE = \frac{0.213 \times{0.48^{2}}}{2}$$
$$KE = 0.0245376J$$

Now to calculate the increase in energy output, just divide modified toy KE by original control toy KE then convert to percentage:

$$Increase = (\frac{KE_{2}}{KE_{1}} - 1) \times100\%$$
$$Increase = (\frac{0.0245376}{0.022343373} - 1) \times100\%$$
$$Increase \approx 9.82\%$$

And 9.82% is quite close to 10%, and is probably close enough *(please leave your opinion).*

Comment: Welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Please be aware that this *not* a homework help site, but you'll find that a good number of the members may be willing to help you, especially when you've put some work into your problem as you have. Since this is a homework problem, I've edited your tags to include. For reference you should do the same for any future questions that are homework related.

Comment: BTW it appears you are on the right track. But here's a hint why experimental data may not match your calculated results: there's something missing in the model. Can some of the energy go somewhere else during the fall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use energy conservation when mass is removed. This has required energy that you are not taking into account.

But you can use **conservation of momentum**. And this is usual, when one speed is unknown, exactly as you have it here.

All moving objects have momentum  $p=mv$, and conservation of momentum says:

$$\sum p_{before} =\sum p_{after} $$

So in you case:

$$ p_{before} = p_{after}
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
m_1v_1=m_2v_2$$

The old and new mass as well as old speed are known, so new speed can be calculated.

Comment: Thanks for that @Steeven and I assume p represents momentum? So therefore:

old mass x old velocity = new speed x new velocity

Is this the correct assumption to make?

Comment: As the answer says, $p$ is momentum, and all momentum before equals all after. Not really an assumption - just another basic conservation law which is very useful to know.